# Maven dependency doesn't bring down correct Selenium version 3.4.0

Tags: maven, selenium

I have a core maven project A which has all the Selenium Firefox driver set up, the pom has

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There is project B, two cases as below:

Case 1: In project B, set project A as dependency in pom.xml, the test always try to connect to Selenium 2.53.1.  I ran as mvn dependency:tree, the project A  only brings Selenium 2.53.1.

Case 2: In eclipse, put project A as "Required projects on the build path" via Properties - Java Build Path - Projects tab, then everything works fine, my test in project B is able to start up Firefox 53.0 using Selenium 3.4.0.

Any idea on that?
Also in eclipse Dependency Hierarchy tab for project B, it shows selenium-java: 2.53.1 (managed from 3.4.0) [test], not sure what is forcing to use the version 2.53.1.

This is the mvn dependency:tree output, selenium-core:1.0.2 is the core project A I mentioned above

```
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test    
[INFO] +- nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:jar:1.5:test
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] +- com.mycompany:selenium-core:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-
driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-
driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-
api:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-
driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:htmlunit-driver:jar:2.21:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.21:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-
js:jar:2.17:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-
htmlunit:jar:2.21:test
[INFO] |  |  |     +- 
net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.18:test
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-
client:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:test
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-
util:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:test
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-
io:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:test
[INFO] |  |  |        +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-
client:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:test
[INFO] |  |  |        |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-
http:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:test
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-
common:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:test
[INFO] |  |  |           \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-
api:jar:9.4.1.v20170120:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-
driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-
driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.2.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-
driver:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.7.Final:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-
support:jar:2.53.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-leg-rc:jar:2.53.1:test
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `mvn dependency:tree` to your post?

Comment: Thanks for your help to look into the issue, I added the dependency project's output

Comment: Try `mvn -U compile`.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @Jingjing - I see some confusing information from your post. You state that your `Project A` brings in `Selenium 3.4.0` but your `mvn dependency:tree` seems to suggest that you are using `selenium 2.53.1`. So it would be good if you Can please help share the `<dependencies>` section of both `Project A` and `Project B` ?

Comment: The output of `mvn dependency:tree` is incomplete, there are 2 levels between `com.mycompany:selenium-core:jar:1.0.2:test` and `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.53.1:test` : whatever is in between (and was edited out) is the culprit.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan I set Selenium 3.4.0 in the pom.xml of project A, but when I put project A as dependency in the pom of project B, then after run mvn dependencey:tree of project B , it shows project A brings down Selenium 2.53.1

Comment: @HuguesM. I added more output info from mvn dependency:tree, looks like there is nothing between com.mycompany:selenium-core:jar:1.0.2:test and org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.53.1:test

Comment: Yes sorry, the missing `[INFO] ` prefix made me see an offset discrepancy where there wasn't. And you don't have a `dependencyManagement` section in A or B? (at this point, it might be worth trying to reproduce the issue with minimal POMs with all sensitive info stripped off)

Comment: Thanks @HuguesM. I will try

Comment: I ended up adding dependency selenium-firefox-driver, selenium-api, selenium-remote-driver and selenium-support  with version 3.4.0 to override the version 2.53.1,  it works now